# Notepad++ select specific part of a line, and set to all other lines

Tags: notepad++

Please, could someone tell me if there's a way to select a part of a line, in a way that ALL the lines 'inserting point' will be select(example: if I type something into a line, it will type in all the others too)?

The point is that I want this to happen WITHOUT having to CTRL + Left Click + drag the mouse for dozens of thousands of lines(I'm talking about almost a hundred thousand lines).

I want it to be something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3BuZ.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: It was supposed to have a picture there...

Comment: and I meant ALT, not CTRL...

Comment: just found out: SHIFT + ALT + Left Click.

Comment: In addition, you can enable [multi-editing](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html)

Comment: Could you use a simple search and replace? It's hard to say what exact pattern would suit your needs from that picture but try pressing `ctrl+h` to bring up the replace window and do a search for `/06/017.`  and replace it with `/06/{WHATEVERYOUNEED}017.`